# Python class variables not updating while inside while loop. (A thread with another function inside the same class is changing them)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to update the value of a variable inside a while loop inside a class.
The value isn't updating and the information I need to transfer isn't reaching.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import random, threading



class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def loop(self):
        while True:
            print(self.players)
    def loop2(self):
        while True:
            self.players = random.randint(1, 100)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TestClass()
    t = threading.Thread(target=a.loop2)
    t.start()
    a.loop()
```

Comment: Try to define that variable as a `global`

Comment: to me it changes the printed number. Why you say it doesnt work ?

Comment: added time.sleep(5) before print(self.players) to have it updated at each print otherwise old variable get printed more than once

Comment: Thank you. My original code was just broken and the changing loop got stuck. Sorry for wasting time.

Comment: whats the fix ?